# TF2.0 create a single pb file without additional folders or files?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I searched and read several articles, but I couldn't find any hint to create a single pb file without variables, assets folder.

My tensorflow version is 2.0.0

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

from this document, I can create a pb file from checkpoint.
and I find a pb file in my folder with this structure.

- pb_file_parent_dir/assets
- pb_file_parent_dir/saved_model.pb
- pb_file_parent_dir/variables/

I want to create one single pb file(saved_model.pb), but I got 2 additional folders (assets and variables).

If there's a way to create a single pb file, then please give me a hand. I want to create a single pb file for deployment purpose.

**Edited**

I tried with 'tf.keras.models.save_model' and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save. I got the same results as above instead of single pb file.

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow 2.0 moves away from using this 'frozen' single file .pb for storing your model in favor of SavedModel format https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model (which is what you have already with a .pb and variables/assets folders) or alternatively you can use Keras .h5 format https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#hdf5_format.

You can still create frozen .pb files in tf2.0 using the compat module, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants but you will have to be using all compat stuff like sessions (which is not the TensorFlow 2.0 way of doing things and not compatible with keras api I believe).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to create a single pb file for deployment(I edited the question). Is there any work around for integrating 'variables' folder and pb file in a single pb file?

I've tried with "tf.trian.latest_checkpoint" function to read the checkpoint and it seemed worked. After that using "tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants" function, it didn't read any node in the graph.

Maybe, I should have tried with version1 approach to read the checkpoint and then use "tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants" function.

Comment: I tried with creating a pb file (saved_model.pb, variables folder, and assert folder). Then, I tried to load with tensorflow 1.14 version, but it failed.. I still have not figured how to do this..

Comment: You should still be able to deploy using saved model format. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: I found a duplicated question and I think it's worth to try it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119155/freezing-graph-to-pb-in-tensorflow2